# How to truncate a string array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Let's say I have a string array with 5 words and I want to only output the first 3 letters of each word. How do I go upon doing this? I know how to do it with one string but with an array of strings I get lost.

This is how to do it with one string

```
std::string test = "hello";

std::cout << test << std::endl;

test = test.substr(0,3);

std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

What I want to do is this

```
std::string test[5] = {"hello", "pumpkin", "friday", "snowboard", "snacks"};
```

I want to cout the first 3 letters of each word. I tried test[5] = test[5].substr(0,3); and that did not work.

Comment: put your code inside a function that takes a single string as a parameter, then call this function in a loop for each string in the array. fun fact about coding: if you can do one you can do them all ;)

Comment: `test[5]` is out of bounds for an array of length `5`. The valid indices are `[0]` through `[4]`

Comment: Time to read a good C++ book.

Comment: @manni66 haha very true, after posting I realized my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

test[5] doesn't work because you only have 5 items in your array, only indexes 0 to 4 are valid.

Generally with arrays you need to write a loop to go through each array item in turn, for instance

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    test[i] = test[i].substr(0,3);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout << test[i] << endl;
```

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to suggest using magic numbers

Comment: @Slava, I wouldn't even say they are magic numbers per se; this is perfectly adequate for an example with concrete requirements. E.g. "I have a string array with 5 words". Also, good usage of ++i over i++

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I knew I needed a loop, I was just not sure where to put the substr(0,3); Much appreciated

Comment: @AlfieJ.Palmer I would not call that perfectly adequate, especially when you can use range based for loop and not use any magic numbers

Comment: @Slava Adequate does not mean best practice. Given the question, it's fairly simple to deduce that OP is new to the technology. I'd argue that the most readable, comprehensive answer will be far more useful than "best practice." That way, they can understand their mistake before aiming to improve it - else they'll have to fight with other trivial details. "What's `auto`?" "Why `const`?" "Why does the `for` look funny?" etc. etc.

Comment: Answer the question in the terms that the OP asked, that's generally what I try to do.

Answer (score 3):

With `test[5]` you are reading out of bounds thus invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Arrays in C++ are zero indexed so the last element would be `test[4]`. Create a function that utilizes for example the [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) function or string's [substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function. Call inside a [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void foo(const std::string& s) {
    if (s.size() >= 3) {
        std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), 3)) << '\n';
        // or simply:
        std::cout << s.substr(0, 3) << '\n';
    }
}
int main() {
    std::string test[5] = { "hello", "pumpkin", "friday", "snowboard", "snacks" };
    for (const auto& el : test) {
        foo(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version with `std::next` would be UB for string too short.

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed. I have updated the answer with some simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 test[5] = test[5].substr(0,3); won't work  and more over you don't have `test[5]`, index starts from `0`.
```

you may want to do like this

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5; i++) {
                test[i] = test[i].substr(0,3);
                cout << test[i] << endl;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr` is what you are looking for. Here is my implementation.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::array<std::string,5> list {"hello", "pumpkin", "friday", "snowboard", "snacks"};

    for (const auto &word : list){
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto &word : list){
        word = word.substr(0,3);
    }

    for (const auto &word : list){
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library.

```
std::for_each(std::begin(test), std::end(test), [] (auto& s) { s.erase(3); });
```

Or even a simple range-based for loop:

```
for (auto&& s : test) {
    s.erase(3); // Erase from index 3 to end of string.
}
```

Or maybe even create another container with views of the original strings:

```
auto test2 = std::accumulate(std::begin(test), std::end(test),
                             std::vector<std::string_view>{},
                             [] (auto& prev, std::string_view sv) -> decltype(prev)& {
    prev.push_back(sv.substr(0, 3));
    return prev;
});
```